# sl4j error in weblogic when deploying grails application war

Tags: exception, grails, weblogic, slf4j

I create a WAR for my grails application and when I deploy it in Weblogic 12c server I get the following Exception

```
<Mar 27, 2012 12:38:55 PM PDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsC
ontextLoaderListener failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/Strin
g;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/la
ng/Throwable;)V
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:582)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Mar 27, 2012 12:38:55 PM PDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.codehaus.groovy.gra
ils.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.
com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.FactoryException: Could not initialize DecoratorMapper : org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.s
itemesh.GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener reg
istered?
        at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.BaseFactory.pushDecoratorMapper(BaseFactory.java:117)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadDecoratorMappers(Grails5535Factory.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadConfig(Grails5535Factory.java:98)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.<init>(Grails5535Factory.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.init(GrailsPageFilter.java:79)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Mar 27, 2012 12:38:55 PM PDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.codehaus.groovy.gra
ils.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationConte
xtUtils.java:84)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.lookupHandlerInterceptors(WebUtils.java:97)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.initFilterBean(UrlMappingsFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:576)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Mar 27, 2012 12:38:55 PM PDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.codehaus.groovy.gra
ils.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationConte
xtUtils.java:84)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.initialize(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:98)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.initFilterBean(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:576)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Mar 27, 2012 12:38:55 PM PDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "grails" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "gr
a.war".
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/la
ng/Throwable;)V
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:301)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Mar 27, 2012 12:39:03 PM PDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1
332877104876" for task "0". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "grails" failed to preload on s
tartup in Web application: "gra.war".
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/la
ng/Throwable;)V
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:301)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:638)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:579)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1738)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCa
llbackDeliverer.java:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallback
Deliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliv
erer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "grails" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "gra.war".
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/la
ng/Throwable;)V
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:301)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:638)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:579)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1738)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCa
llbackDeliverer.java:195)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallback
Deliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliv
erer.java:68)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1706)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/Stri
ng;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:301)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Mar 27, 2012 12:39:04 PM PDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 1 task for
 the application "gra".>
<Mar 27, 2012 12:39:04 PM PDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for applicat
ion "gra".>
<Mar 27, 2012 12:39:04 PM PDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "grails" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "gra.war".
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/la
ng/Throwable;)V
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:301)
```

The Entire Trace is really long but basically as I am seeing it, it looks like some isuue with Sl4j api. Not sure what is the cause since the application runs fine when I do run-app directly without WAR and even with the WAR delpoyed in Tomcat Server v6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The version bundled in Weblogic of SLF4J is 1.6.1 and grails comes with 1.5.10

If you're using maven then see this thread:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?124753-Spring-mvc-sample-project-slf4j-problem&p=407143

You can try using a PARENT_LAST/CHILD_FIRST classloader option or removing the slf4j wars from the grails WAR

Ex from [Grails Deployment](http://grails.org/Deployment) page on how to remove Wars:

```
//Remove logging libs from grails app because they're already supplied by Jboss - BuildConfig.groovy

grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
   for (name in ['log4j', 'slf4j', 'jcl-over-slf4j', 'jul-to-slf4j']) {
      delete {
         fileset dir: "$stagingDir/WEB-INF/lib/",
                 includes: "$name*.jar"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesnot remove the error, the grails has a dependency on this version, we cannot use the other version from weblogic. The final step we took was to rollback the weblogic server version to 10.3.6.0 and that uses sl4j version same as grails expects or the grails plugins expect

Comment: Why not isolating the classloader by setting weblogic.xml?