# Grails org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log not found

Tags: grails, slf4j, grails-2.3

I'm using Grails 2.3.8

I've created a default app using

```
grails create-app testapp
```

When I run:

```
grails runApp
```

I get the following issue:

```
| Configuring classpath
| Error Error executing script RunApp: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory$Slf4jLoggerEx.debug(Slf4jLoggerFactory.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider.newLocalRepositoryManager(DefaultLocalRepositoryProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.newLocalRepositoryManager(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:421)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy:513)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.doResolve(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure17.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:774)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultBuildDependencies_closure17.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:768)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getBuildDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:673)
| Error Error executing script RunApp: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

I tried running:

```
grails dependency-report
```

but I get the same issue.

```
java -version
```

gives:

```
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but I *vaguely* recall there being some problems with Groovy and the earlier versions of Java 7. I'd recommend moving to the most recent. I have no problems with 2.3.8 and jdk1.7.0_55 (most recent at time of writing).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked for conflicting versions of slf4j? Try running Grails dependency-report.

There are a few other SO questions that indicate this to be a cause of issue. Eg: [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537459/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-slf4j-spi-locationawarelogger-log)

[sl4j error in weblogic when deploying grails application war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897722/sl4j-error-in-weblogic-when-deploying-grails-application-war?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can help in debugging situations like this is doing:

```
  export JAVA_OPTS="-verbose"
```

You can then see which slf4j JAR is being loaded by the JVM, but yes there is undoutably some conflicing slf4j JAR on your classpath

Answer (score 0):

There was an instance of slf4j in:

```
/Library/Java/Extensions/
```

Moving that out seems to have fixed the problem.